# Set class after css3 animation

Tags: css, animation

I use animate.css. 
I need to change the class of the element after the animation. If you use the js it works asynchronously.

I see it like this:

```
@keyframes bounceInUp {
  0%, 60%, 75%, 90%, 100% {..}
  0% {..}
  60% {..}
  75% {..}
  90% {..}
  100% {
    ..
    div#id {
      /*change css*/
    }
  }
}
```

But it does not work.  Help me please :-)

Comment: Do you want to change the class or some of the properties? You cannot change the class of an element directly from CSS. You can however change some properties during animation and make the element retain the values as at its final keyframe. A more complete example of what you need will be better to provide a full answer.

Comment: I need to replace some of the properties of an element by ID

Comment: Is it the same element that is being animated or a different element? If it is  a different element, then it is not possible with pure CSS. And as I mentioned in my previous comment, an example on what you are trying to do would go a long way towards getting a good answer.

Comment: I need after the animation to hide some fields

Comment: Through js they hide at once, and do not want to use a timer.

Comment: If it is a different element then I am almost certain that you would need to use JS (or some libraries). CSS won't help much there.

Comment: You just need to implement 'AnimationEnd' event handler in JS.